# Gimp : How to make a selection with the current background color considered transparent?

Tags: gimp, transparency

Just like in Paint, how can I do a "transparent selection"? For example, if red is the background color and I select a part of an image with red in it, I want my selection to consider the the red to be transparent.

Or equivalently : How can I change a specific color inside a selection to transparent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Transparent selection with GIMP

Below are some possible approaches using default GIMP 2.8. without additional plugins.

#### Color to Alpha:

To make the background color in a selection transparent we may take the following steps:

1. [image] **Edit - Copy** the selection
2. [image] **Edit - Paste** the selection
3. [image] **Colors - Color to Alpha...** choose background color

Note that in the example above the color channel for red is completely made transparent leading to a "transparency" with color shift in the grey area too. Depending on our source this may not be what we wanted.

#### Select By Color

1. [image] **Edit - Copy** the selection
2. **Edit - Paste as - New Image** to work on a new image
3. [image] **Tools - Selection Tools - By Color Select** selects all the background
4. [image] **Delete** the selection
5. **Select - Invert**
6. **Edit - Copy** the selection
7. [image] **Edit - Paste** the selection to our source.

Again, depending on the source image we may find it faster to apply the **By Color Select** tool directly on the image background, invert this selection, then copy & paste it to the destiny (or as a new image for further processing).

Comment: That is good, but I tried the second method and there is still a small line of red around the selection.

Comment: I think your answer is the closest to what I want to do.

Comment: Thank you - but don't hesitate to unaccept if a better solution comes in - I would love to see that myself ;)